# Mounting devices to mountpoints stored in variables

Tags: bash, centos, mount, variable

Im doing this script and I cant see to find a way to accordingly mount the devices stored in the "devs" variable into the mount points listed in "mntpnt".

Hope Im being clear explaining myself, heres the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(find /dev/sd{b..z}1 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
dirnames=$(printf "win%d " $(seq $count))

for i in $dirnames
do
        sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$i
done

devs=$(find /dev/sd{b..z}1 2>/dev/null)
mntpnt=$(find /mnt/win*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to mount all the existing devices' first positions you don't need to determine them and save them. You can just mount them as you iterate:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
for dev in /dev/sd[b-z]1
do
    mnt="/mnt/win$((i+=1))"
    sudo mkdir -p "$mnt"
    sudo mount "$dev" "$mnt"
done
```

If I were writing this for me I wouldn't include the `sudo` commands. Instead I'd require the script to be run under `sudo`. Push the realisation that this script needs root privileges back to the user.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I completely understood the explanation and the script !

Comment: done ! Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Note that `++i` is not standard `sh` syntax (though works in most sh implementations especially the ones typically found on Linux based systems). See `$((i+=1))` for a standard equivalent.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you. Happy to oblige. If I'm writing `sh` I would prefer it to be standard

Comment: @zevzek, yes, it's unary `+` applied twice. Thanks. I forgot `dash` didn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```bsh
find /dev -name "*sd[b-z]1" | \
  while IFS= read -r i; do
    dir="/mnt/win${i##*[^1]}"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dir"
    sudo mount "$i" "$dir"
  done
```

Comment: Could you explain me what IFS does like if I’m a kid? It’s the only part I don’t understand, I googled already but I still don’t get it. Thanks.